# Basic concept clarification about the expectation value formula in quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vacuum, klein-gordon-equation

In introducing quantum field theory, the field solution to the Klein-Gordon equation is $$\phi(x^{\mu}) = \int \frac{a_{\bf{k}} e^{-i(k^{\mu}x_{\mu})} + a^{\dagger}_{\bf{k}} e^{i(k^{\mu}x_{\mu})}}{\sqrt{2\omega(2\pi)^3}} d\omega$$

The commutation relation is then $$[\phi(t, {\bf{x}}), \phi(t, {\bf{x^{'}}})] = 0$$
The vacuum state is introduced as a "no particle" observation, and the precise inner workings of what particles mean can be "hidden" for introductory purposes inside the ket $|0\rangle$. I am struggling with the exact mathematical treatment however, as I cannot expand the fundamental equations $a_{{\bf{k}}}^{\dagger}|0\rangle = |1_{{\bf{k}}}\rangle , a_{{\bf{k}}}|0\rangle = 0$ to arrive at $\langle0|\phi|0\rangle = 0$. I assume the $\phi$ operates before the integration w.r.t. $d\omega$ is taken, but are the normal modes "replaced" by the vacuum state? Or are the modes multiplied by the vacuum state?$$$$
Also, the Green function of the free field operator is $$G(x;x^{'}) = -i \langle0|[\phi(t, {\bf{x}}), \phi(t, {\bf{x^{'}}})]|0\rangle$$
which I can define by constructing the green function from first principles but I don't actually know why this is true or what it really means. Besides, I would naively expect a trivial $0$ as the answer as the commutator is $0$. $$$$
My question is how to define the expectation value in quantum field theory. I am aware of a derivation using path-integral quantization but the source I'm learning from introduces this much later so I suppose I'm searching for a basic answer using the limited structure described. Thanks.

Comment: You will have to read a whole lot more. There is a lot of baggage involved. Let us talk about the free field case you are learning now. The $\phi$ is made of creation and annihilation operators, which, upon acting on the vacuum state, makes particles and antiparticles appear. Those states are orthogonal to the vacuum states, so you ought to get zero expectation value no matter what. However, note that this is very much fiction. In interacting field theory we cannot expand in creation and annihilation operators like that, although we continue to pretend this is true in general.

Comment: As for the Green's function, it is likely you read it wrongly. It would have been much better if people taught QM using the green's functions way to solve things, so that then we can have an easier transition to QFT, but alas, professors are lazy

Comment: The time co-ordinates are not equal in $x$ and $x^\prime$.

Comment: All you need for $\langle 0|\phi|0\rangle=0$ is that $\langle 0|a_{\bf k}|0\rangle=0$ and $\langle 0|a^\dagger_{\bf k}|0\rangle=0$.

Comment: @mikestone But the normal modes $u_{\bf{k}}$ are "in the way" so to speak of the annihilation and creation operators operating on the vacuum state/ket?

Comment: What do you mean by "in the way"?  The modes are c-number functions  and therefore commute with the $a$'s

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent The source material I'm using is "Quantum field in curved space", Birell and Davies (1982), and the green function equation is on page 20 as I have written, where the Wightman functions are then identified as each component.

Comment: @mikestone I think that's the precisely insight I was looking for, thank you! so $(\int a_{\bf{k}} u_{\bf{k}} d\omega) |0\rangle = (\int a_{\bf{k}} u_{\bf{k}} |0\rangle d\omega) = (\int a_{\bf{k}} |0\rangle u_{\bf{k}} d\omega) = 0$, a little confused if the integration is performed before or after the "operating". Also would really appreciate your insight on the vacuum expectation value of the comutator of the free fields. Thanks again